# Put V+ing in the beginning of sentence

Tags: grammar

Here are my questions

Should it be

> V+ing + something + simple past / past participle ?

or should it be

> V+ing + something + to simple present?/ or + simple present ?

Or rather there never had

> V+ing + anything above ?

My example sentence:

> Considering so many reasons pushed me to watch this movie, I finally bought the ticket.

My options:

> 1. Considering so many reasons have pushed me to watch this movie , I.........
> 2. Considering so many reasons push me to watch this movie , I...............
> 3. Considering so many reasons to push me (to watch? / watch? / watching?) this movie, I.....

Please tell me which of those are correct, and thank you!

Comment: Another (and probably a valid) possibility: *Considering so many reasons **pushing** me watch this movie, I ...* But depending on the context, all options are possible I think!

Comment: Sentences #1 and #2 sound grammatically correct. As for #3, to push me to watch is correct. Bare infinitive "watch" is incorrect. Also watching is wrong. You have to say to push me to watch or to push me into watching this movie, I ......

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is correct, and is in the past tense. You're saying that in the past, many things have pushed you until you finally, in the present, watch the movie.

Your second example is in the present tense, many things are *currently* pushing you to watch the movie, so you finally see it.

Your third example is incorrect. You can't use *reasons* in the general sense, you need to introduce them with the phrase 'there is/are' or a definite/indefinite article. The following examples are correct:

1. There are good reasons to push me to see the movie
2. This is a good reason to push me to see the movie
3. Considering the best reason to push me to watch he movie is...
4. Considering a good reason to push me to watch the movie is...

In these examples, I'm talking in a hypothetical sense. I'm saying that if you *want* to push me, I'm going to give you a good reason you could use to convince me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to end all sentences as in your example (...I finally bought the ticket),

Strictly speaking, all your proposed options are incorrect, as is the example itself, because it either needs a "that" after "considering", or after "reasons" (in which case you might better have said "the many reasons that pushed me").

But you were asking, I think, about the verb tenses, so I'll answer in regard to that.

In the first option, the verb tense "pushed" is simple past, which is correct; it matches with "bought".  You could also have used past perfect "had pushed".

The second is incorrect because "have pushed" is present perfect tense, which does not go with "bought" .

In the third: this would be grammatically correct if you choose "to watch". And the infinitive "to push" works, as it implies no tense, and fits with "bought". However, stylistically speaking, "to push me to watch" has two infinitives close together: "pushing me to watch" would flow even better.

Answer (score -1):

Briefly speaking, your given sentences are correct grammatically as well as according to different contexts.